# Fluidpages Flux Configuration inheritance incomplete

Tags: typo3, fluid, flux, fedext

I'm currently using TYPO3 6.1.8-dev to build a flux/fluidpages (GitHub Master) powered template and managed to have it running on the root pages, though, I have issues with the sub-pages, in terms of value inheritance.

I've implemented the following scenario:

A Flux Flexform Configuration is used, if there is no TypoScript override variable set, retrieved from TS Setup.
The Flexform fields have the following names:

```
gridsettings.topRow_use (checkbox)
gridsettings.topRow_cols (select)
```

After the Flexform Configuration, I use these fields to build the backend grid, after I mix in some static values of a TypoScript configuration with:

```
{v:iterator.merge(a:'{gridsettings}', b:'{tssettings}') ->  v:var.set(name:'gridsettings')}
```

This works for every page with explicit settings in the page properties, but not for sub-pages, which should just inherit the parents settings.
In the case of sub-pages the gridsettings array is null, and only my  TS settings are visible.

I'd like to have the convenience to just create a new sub-page, and add content to the inherited backend-layout grid without any further interaction in the page settings.

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Two parts to this:

1) To solve the problem that you manually must merge TS with FlexForm settings, use the prefix `settings.` in all your field names. This special, reserved variable name will be used by both Extbase and Fluid without requiring you to transfer it, and your FlexForm settings will be merged (on top of) your TS settings.

2) Inheritance requires the exact same page template on parent and child page, or that child page sets `parent decides` as option for which template to use. There could be other causes for failing inheritance (for example, the use of `default` on any of your fields - since you don't include your Flux form structure this is impossible to determine) but mismatching parent/child template is the most common. Also, make sure your Flux is up-to-date; there have been bugfixes recently related to inheritance.